# ignore comma between quotes

Tags: swift, uikit, foundation

My program reads a line from a file. This line contains comma-separated text like:

123,111,test,"don't split, this",123
I would like the result of a split to be this:

```
123
111
test
"don't split, this"
123
```

If I use the string.components(separatedBy: ",") I would get this:

```
123
111
test
"don't split
 this"
123
```

In other words: The comma in the substring "don't split, this" is not a separator. How to deal with this?

Comment: Old, but a potential lead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655852/swiftcsv-parser-support-for-doublequotes or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206930/csv-parsing-swift-4

Comment: try to separate it via \n (new line), then trim commas at the end of each string.

Comment: why are you trying to separate by comma, if (from provided example) each item you want is on a separate line? something is amiss on a provided example